# If $S$ is dense in $X$ and $S\subset T$, then $T$ is dense in $X$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Problem is from Topology without Tears by Morris

> If $S$ is dense in $X$ and $S\subset T$, then  $T$ is dense in $X$.

**Try**

Assume $S$ is dense in $X$. Suppose $S\cap X=\varnothing$. Then every element of $X\setminus S$  is a limit point of $S$. By hypothesis  $S\subset T$  so every element of $X\setminus T$  is a limit point of $T$.

Thus $T$ is dense in $X$.

I am not too good with this topic. I basically tweaked a theorem and hope it works

Help

Comment: is true that $S \subset X$ and $T \subset X$?

Comment: A set $S$ is dense in a set $T$ if and only if $U\cap S\ne\varnothing$ for every non-empty (relatively) open subset of $T$. In my experience this is frequently the most useful way to view denseness. It certainly is here: every non-empty open subset of $X$ intersects $S$, so it certainly intersects $T$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty easy, since closure respects containment, so to speak.  That is, $S\subset T\implies\bar S\subset\bar T$.  That is by the definition of closure, say as the smallest closed set containing the given set.

Comment: I proved that already @ChrisCuster

Comment: Then there you are.

Comment: Huh so by proving that I can claim S is dense X -> T is dense in X @ChrisCuster

Comment: Yes. As I said, this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Last question,so what I wrote makes no sense

Comment: I don't think you should start with $S\cap X=\emptyset$, for starters.  Otherwise ok.

Answer (score 0):

If any non-empty open subset of $X$ intersects $S$, a fortiori it also intersects $T$. So $T$ is dense whenever $S$ is.

Comment: I use a criterion from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set): a set is dense iff every non-empty open set intersects it.

Comment: I feel dense doing topology.Thanks Henno